# Does Tweeting "from the river to the sea" result in a suspension from Twitter?

Tags: israel, censorship, twitter

As reported by [Jewish Press](https://www.jewishpress.com/headline/from-the-river-to-the-sea-to-result-in-suspension-from-x/2023/11/18/), Musk [first Tweeted](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1724936047489167852),

> Yes, “decolonization” necessarily implies a Jewish genocide, thus it is unacceptable to any reasonable person

[Musk since clarified with](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1725645884409401435)

> As I said earlier this week, “decolonization”, **“from the river to the sea”** and similar euphemisms necessarily imply genocide.
>
> Clear calls for extreme violence are against our terms of service and **will result in suspension**.

Does tweeting either “decolonization”, or “from the river to the sea”, result in a suspension from Twitter?

Comment: Huh, I would have guessed some careless journalist split the quote, but apparently that's how  Musk put it. I guess Twitter middle-management toned it down or they don't have enough people or even AI bots to enforce it exactly as Musk said. Or he mistyped what he meant, or changed his mind a little, etc.

Comment: See this: [Is "From the River to the Sea, Palestine Will Be Free" a call for genocide?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/56356/61574)

Comment: Germany might help here: "While promoting free speech, [Musk] has approved 80% of governmental requests to remove information from Twitter, up from about 50% under the platform’s previous leadership." ([src](https://forward.com/culture/555903/elon-musk-twitter-free-speech-defamation/)) I guess somebody from Germany needs to flag your tweets and their gov't to inform Twitter, since they're illegal there, I've heard.

Comment: (If you're curious how they came up with that figure "The tech outlet makes those assertions based on data submitted by Twitter itself to the Lumens database—a giant public catalogue of legal and government requests submitted to online platforms." -- https://gizmodo.com/elon-musk-twitter-content-moderation-twitter-files-1850384315)

Comment: @Fizz You are talking about Twitter/X obeying German law, going from 50% to 80% obeying the law in general is not something to be proud of. The question however seems to ask about policies that Twitter/X applies on their own as general terms of service and one would assume this applies world wide.

Comment: What is it you are skeptical about? The owner of Twitter has stated the policy. The policy may not be applied in every case, but that's not the point.

Comment: @DJClayworth: well, the OP got suspended on SX, ha ha.

Comment: And tweeting calls for genocide, even in a coded form, is something that should warrant a suspension, if not worse. Posting the 14 words will also get you a ban on social media, even though there isn't anything directly offensive in them, because context is everything.

Comment: @Fizz: Why the OP got suspended?

Comment: @Fizz - I don't know, but good old Elon does not seem like much of a champion of freedom of expression as he claimed. At least, insofar as he claimed that people should be as free to say what they wanted on Twitter as they are in other contexts.

Comment: @C.F.G Fizz isn't a moderator, so they're probably not privy to that information, and even if they were, moderators generally aren't at liberty to talk about other people's suspensions. Judging from the suspension reason listed in their profile - "This account is temporarily suspended to cool down" - I'm guessing they got a bit too heated in the comments somewhere.

Comment: @F1Krazy I know that Fizz is not a Mod, I asked Fizz because Fizz said "ha ha".

Comment: Well, good to know Alex Jones is back on X, after a "democratic" poll. https://www.npr.org/2023/12/10/1218431610/elon-musk-restores-x-account-of-conspiracy-theorist-alex-jones I wonder if Musk conducted something like that before deciding to ban the word "decolonization".